# How to save datetime object prettytable to sort as date instead of like a string

Tags: python, sorting, datetime, prettytable

I have the following prettytable:
import operator

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable


table = PrettyTable(["Name","Month", "Grade"])
table.title="title test" 
table.add_row(["Joe","Jan", 90])
table.add_row(["Sally", "Feb", 100])
table.add_row(["Bill", "Mar", 90])
table.add_row(["Alice", "April", 90])
print(table.get_string( sortby="Month"))
```

This produces the following:

```
+-----------------------+
|       title test      |
+-------+-------+-------+
|  Name | Month | Grade |
+-------+-------+-------+
| Alice | April |   90  |
| Sally |  Feb  |  100  |
|  Joe  |  Jan  |   90  |
|  Bill |  Mar  |   90  |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

I am trying to sort by the `Month` column but since it is a string it is not treating it like a `datetime`. Could you please advise how can i save a datetime object inside prettytable so i can sort it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort_key` keyword-argument on the `get_string` method and pass it a lambda function that converts the month name into an integer:

```py
from prettytable import PrettyTable

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

table = PrettyTable(["Name","Month", "Grade"])
table.title="title test" 
table.add_row(["Joe","Jan", 90])
table.add_row(["Sally", "Feb", 100])
table.add_row(["Bill", "Mar", 90])
table.add_row(["Alice", "Apr", 90])

print(table.get_string(sortby="Month", sort_key=lambda row: months.index(row[2]))) # where row[2] is the second item of the row (it's 1-based, *not* 0-based)
```

Note that the row that gets passed to the lambda function has four items—you'll want to access columns from it using 1-based indexing, not 0-based like you might be inclined to think.

Comment: Could you please share a link with me where i can learn more about 1 0-based indexing and understand what it means?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering